# Git SVN case sensitive folder names

Tags: git, git-svn, case-sensitive

In SVN I have the following structure:

```
|- Post/index.jsp
|- post/index.jsp
```

The two JSP files are different on a single line from each other:

```
-    <title>Post</title>
+    <title>post</title>
```

When I do a `git svn rebase` I only get one of these folders in the actual working directory (let's say `Post`), and under the very same folder the index.jsp is marked as a changed file in my index, where the difference is saying that I've changed the title from `Post` to `post`. After trying to do a `git checkout` on the file, I get the whole thing the other way around, so basically no matter what I do I always end up having uncommitted changes...

So far I've been trying to set `core.ignorecase = true` in my git config, but that didn't really help, not even after a `git reset --hard SHA1` and a `git svn reset -r <REV>` to revisions prior to the addition of these files and doing the rebase again.

This is all happening on OSX, is there any workaround for dealing with such repository layouts with git svn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X partitions are by default *case-preserving* but not *case-sensitive*. You either need to create a new partition and make it case-senstive or re-think your naming strategy.

The following screen shot shows the default setting for new partitions: `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` - you would need to change this to: `Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)`.

[image: Disk Utility - setting partition to case sensitive]

Comment: Yepp, it seems I just didn't really realize that OSX is not case sensitive by default, in any case this solution will most likely resolve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Note: don't make your main OS X partition case-sensitive - it will break certain apps etc - use a secondary partition for case-sensitive stuff which you just use for source code, documents, data, etc.